# "not defined" problem in function in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there any way to solve "not defined" problem in the function definitions without using "global"? The script works well in python but when I converted the script to exe, global function doesn't work, so it turns into an error in the exe program: "weclass not defined".

```
def browse_file():
    filepath = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("xlsx", "*.xlsx"), ("all files", "*.*"))) #===assigns the path to filepath
    label = Label(root, text=filepath) #==Adds Label to window 
    label.pack()
    global weclass
    weclass = pd.read_excel(filepath)
    return weclass

frame_ust=Frame(root, bg="#0023b0")
frame_ust.place(relx=0.25, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.25, relheight=0.1)
B1 = Button(frame_ust, text ="pick file", command = browse_file)
B1.pack()
```

Comment: The value returned from a button callback function is ignored, so the `return weclass` is worthless. Regardless, you might be able to fix the problem by adding a `weclass  = None` *outside* the function at the module level, so it will be defined whether the function is called or not.

Comment: I couldnt get the point. What do you mean by at the module level?

Comment: Every Python script is a "module", so I meant define it a the highest level, outside of anything else, like a function or a class.

Comment: When I defined the dataframe outside of the function, it remains what I defined. The function doesnt change the dataframe as in the function. BTW, I dont want to use global in the function.

Comment: If you want a function to change the value of something other than a local variable, you *must* use a global variable and declare as such in the function. One way to work around that requirement is by using classes.

Comment: But at that time, when I turn the script into exe, global function is ignored or doesn't work.

Comment: I didn't say to make it a global *function*. There's really nothing more to say without more information.

Comment: I mean using global as shown in the script not as a function. What I try to find a way is to get the dataframe from the function without using global inside the function.

Comment: I understand what you want to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246001/discussion-between-fyec-and-martineau).

Comment: I went to chat but you never responded. Have you tried my answer?

Comment: I responded in the chat.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this for obvious reasons, but here's a way to do it without declaring a global variable. Instead a *mutable* global variable is passed to the function as an argument and the function modifies that. Actually, the variable passed to it does not have to be a global, it could be a list defined in a function or class method.

```
def browse_file(result):
    # Assigns the path to filepath
    filepath = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("xlsx", "*.xlsx"), ("all files", "*.*")))
    label = Label(root, text=filepath) #==Adds Label to window
    label.pack()
    weclass = pd.read_excel(filepath)
    result.append(weclass)

data = []  # Mutable object to receive result of calling browse_file().
frame_ust = Frame(root, bg="#0023b0")
frame_ust.place(relx=0.25, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.25, relheight=0.1)
B1 = Button(frame_ust, text ="pick file", command=lambda: browse_file(data))
B1.pack()
```